# How to make a input in Admin page as password type?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I created a model which has 3 fields: name, email, password. I want the password in the admin to not show as clear text or to not show even. Do you have
any ideas to change input type in the admin page from type='text' to type='password'?

[image: image of password input in my admin page]

Models.py:

```py
class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False,blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=False,blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.artist_name
```

admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from home.models import Track, Artist, Region, User
admin.site.register(Artist)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing passwords in plaintext. Are you authenticating users using the `Artist` model? (Can you not use the Django built-in `User` model?)

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about hiding the password for security purposes ? -use authentication like passport instead, or even hashing, encryption etc.

or are you talking about instead of displaying "password123" it displays "***********" ?
this can be done but the password can be discovered easily by anyone with basic knowledge of computers

Comment: i want the password to diplay as **** , i just want to test